# Is there any reason to escape user input if it is just going to be hashed and stored as a password?

Tags: php

Is there any reason to escape user input if it is just going to be hashed and stored as a password? It will never be displayed anywhere or outputted to the user. Is there any inherent danger of code injection during the hashing/unhashing process or anywhere else along the line?

Comment: that depends on the hash, and what it outputs, and if any of that output could potentially contain sql metacharacters. e.g.a  real sha/md5 raw hash is just binary garbage, and can NATURALLY contain metacharacters. And if you were using proper prepared statements with placeholders, then you don't have to worry AT ALL about escaping.

Comment: No. If you're  [using the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) there is no need to escape anything.

Comment: if you escape it before you hash it, you change it so the user typed password will no longer match

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything as I am so new to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two moments when we might want to escape an input:

1. when we put it in our SQL statement;
2. when we output it.

As you told us, the second one will never/you expect it to never be the case, and if it was, we usually escape it before outputting it, not before putting it in the database, so you are fine.

For the first case, it is to prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). If you use PDO, as it is recommended, and if you use the `prepare()` method, then you are fine, because PDO takes care of securing the string so that it can't affect the database (it escapes it, basically).